# PHP - Calling internal API

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in PHP.
I created a Laravel project using *composer**.
My controller has two endpoint **uploadFile** and **testpost**:

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request) {
    //there are more code about reading uploaded file here. Everything is OK here.

    $request = Request::create('/api/testpost', 'POST',
        [],[],[],[],'{"this is" : "my test content"}');
    return Route::dispatch($request);
}

public function testpost(Request $request){
    Log::info($request->all());

    return response()->json(["title"=>"this is the test get method"]);
}
```

*uploadFile* is invoked by POST action from a form which carries an uploaded JSON file.
I want to call **testpost** inside of **uploadFile** method using *Request::create(...)* and *Route::dispatch(...)*.
*testpost* is invoked however the body of request is not as expected. The log file shows me that *$request->all()* does not return the request body which I expect to be *{"this is" : "my test content"}*.

My log file:

```
[2019-02-23 12:16:47] local.INFO: array (
  '_token' => 'JzQjclRD4WaTkezqLxlU48D1dM7S3X2X3hok3kr4',
  'employee_file' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'test_input_file.txt',
     'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

What wrong in my code? API invocation or request body retrieval?
I know that we can call *testpost* method directly instead of calling API. However, I ultimate purpose is to know how to call an internal API.

Comment: That's a very weird method to dispatch requests, and I think the reason of your issue is that original request is overlaps that you created manually.

Comment: I would expect something like HttpClient in .Net but I could not find it.

Comment: If you were using `laravel/installer` that you also have `GuzzleHttp/Guzzle` package installed globally. That's what you'd want to use. Docs: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use internal API calls for this.

If both methods are in the same class you can invoke directly with

```
$this->methodName($args);
```

and it will return the result directly to the calling function. (provided you have a return statement in the method you are invoking)

Comment: I know what you mean. Actually, I need to create two projects, one for the API, another one for the web app which calls that API. I just make the first step by calling the internal API like that to learn how to call API using PHP.